# Parse Tab Delimited String

Tags: parsing, lisp, common-lisp, csv

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to separate a string which is tab delimited into chunks of data as an example if i have a text file which I'm reading from that looks like this

```
a1     b1     c1     d1     e1
a2     b2     c2     d2     e2
```

and i read the first line of my file and get a string which of

```
"a1     b1     c1     d1      e2"
```

I want to separate this into 5 variables a,b,c,d and e, or create a list (a b c d e). Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: please show us what you have written so far.

Comment: I haven't written anything yet, My original code is written in Perl and i need to convert it lisp, I don't really know what is the best way to do it. I'm starting to think it may be easier to instead of reading a txt file just to incorporate into the program and then changed it as need be

Answer (score 2):

Try concatenating parentheses onto the front and back of your input string, then using `read-from-string` (I assume you're using Common Lisp, since you tagged your question clisp).

```
(setf str "a1   b1      c1      d1      e2")
(print (read-from-string (concatenate 'string "(" str ")")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way to go about it (a tad more robust, perhaps), You can also easily modify it so that you could `setf' a character in the string once the callback is called, but I didn't do it that way because it seemed like you don't need this sort of ability. Also, in that later case, I'd rather use a macro.

```
(defun mapc-words (function vector
                  &aux (whites '(#\Space #\Tab #\Newline #\Rubout)))
  "Iterates over string `vector' and calls the `function'
with the non-white characters collected so far.
The white characters are, by default: #\Space, #\Tab
#\Newline and #\Rubout.
`mapc-words' will short-circuit when `function' returns false."
  (do ((i 0 (1+ i))
       (start 0)
       (len 0))
      ((= i (1+ (length vector))))
    (if (or (= i (length vector)) (find (aref vector i) whites))
        (if (> len 0)
            (if (not (funcall function (subseq vector start i)))
                (return-from map-words)
                (setf len 0 start (1+ i)))
            (incf start))
        (incf len))) vector)

(mapc-words
 #'(lambda (word)
     (not
      (format t "word collected: ~s~&" word)))
 "a1     b1     c1     d1     e1
a2     b2     c2     d2     e2")

;; word collected: "a1"
;; word collected: "b1"
;; word collected: "c1"
;; word collected: "d1"
;; word collected: "e1"
;; word collected: "a2"
;; word collected: "b2"
;; word collected: "c2"
;; word collected: "d2"
;; word collected: "e2"
```

Here's an example macro you could use, if you wanted to modify the string as you read it, but I'm not entirely happy with it, so maybe someone will come up with a better variant.

```
(defmacro with-words-in-string
    ((word start end
           &aux (whites '(#\Space #\Tab #\Newline #\Rubout)))
     s
     &body body)
  `(do ((,end 0 (1+ ,end))
        (,start 0)
        (,word)
        (len 0))
       ((= ,end (1+ (length ,s))))
     (if (or (= ,end (length ,s)) (find (aref ,s ,end) ',whites))
         (if (> len 0)
             (progn
               (setf ,word (subseq ,s ,start ,end))
               ,@body
               (setf len 0 ,start (1+ ,end)))
             (incf ,start))
         (incf len))))

(with-words-in-string (word start end)
    "a1     b1     c1     d1     e1
a2     b2     c2     d2     e2"
(format t "word: ~s, start: ~s, end: ~s~&" word start end))
```

Comment: I'm not really happy with aspects of design of MAP-WORDS. I would not put in the exit functionality. The CL library does not use it and exiting out of the mapping could be done by the provided function itself (using any of the CL mechanisms: returns, throwing, condition signalling, ...). CL also does not use the name 'callback'. This implies something slightly different (event driven or access oriented). In the CL standard the 'function' is used. 'x' should be 'vector'. 'map-words' should be 'mapc-words' and return the vector.

Comment: (remove-if #'consp some-list :count 10), REMOVE-IF also has a KEY parameter.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that they are tabbed (not spaced) then this will create a list

```
(defun tokenize-tabbed-line (line)
  (loop 
     for start = 0 then (+ space 1)
     for space = (position #\Tab line :start start)
     for token = (subseq line start space)
     collect token until (not space)))
```

which results in the following:

```
CL-USER> (tokenize-tabbed-line "a1  b1  c1  d1  e1")
("a1" "b1" "c1" "d1" "e1")
```